# awk - match strings containing characters in both upper & lower case and blank spaces

Tags: awk

I have an input file in .csv format which contains entries of tax invoices separated by comma.

for example:

```
Header--TIN | NAME | INV NO | DATE | NET | TAX | OTHERS | TOTAL
Record1-29001234768 | A S Spares | AB012 | 23/07/2016 | 5600 | 200 | 10 | 5810
Record2-29450956221 | HONDA Spare Parts | HOSS0987 |29/09/2016 | 70000 | 2200 | 0 | 72200
```

My aim is to process these records using 'AWK'.
My requirements-

1) I need to check the 'NAME' field for special characters and digits (i.e it should only be an alphabetical string) and the length of string (including Spaces) in the 'NAME' field should not exceed 30.
If the above conditions are not satisfied I should report error to the user by printing the error records only

2) I need to check the 'INV NO' field for special characters including blank spaces (INV NO is an alphanumeric field). I also need to check the length of the contents of this field and it should not exceed 15.

Can anyone please give me the regular expression to match these above requirements and also the procedure of how to implement it.

Comment: There isn't a single comma in your Comma-Separated-Value sample input. [edit] your question so the example is consistent with the text it supports and add the expected output given your sample input.

Comment: I have used 'sed' command to replace all comma's with pipelines with space on either sides , for better understandability.

Comment: It does the opposite. Don't do that. That's like having a problem with your Honda but taking your Toyota to the mechanic to diagnose the Honda problem because your Toyota looks better. When posting a [mcve] show real values, not something else as that just wastes the time of people who don't spot the inconsistency (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39376233/1745001) and you end up with fewer possible answers as the rest of us aren't sure what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
awk -f check.awk input.csv
```

where `check.awk` is:

```
BEGIN {
  FS=","  # the input field separator
}

# skip the header (NR>1), check regex for field 2, check length of field 2
NR>1 && $2 ~ /[^a-zA-Z ]/ || length($2)>30 {print "error w NAME "$1}

# skip the header (NR>1), check regex for field 3, check length of field 3
NR>1 && $3 ~ /[^0-9a-zA-Z]/ || length($3)>15 {print "error with INV NO "$1}
```

If you use `gawk` you can use the `IGNORECASE` global and use case-insensitive regexs

Answer (score 0):

If your system has a modern `grep` (i.e. one that supports the `-P` option) then it I think would be easier to solve this using `grep`, e.g. like this:

```
grep -viP '^[^|]* \| [a-z0-9 ]{0,30} \| [a-z0-9]{0,15} \|' file.txt
```

The above command should print all lines that do not satisfy your requirements.